# PostgreSQL CASE statement syntax error

Tags: case, postgresql-9.1

I'm trying to follow the instructions in the PostgreSQL manual. 
[PostgreSQL: Documentation: 9.1: Control Structures](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html)
My PostgreSQL server is version 9.1.14 on Windows 32-bit.

The following SQL statement is unexpectedly resulting in a syntax error:

```
SELECT
  CASE 1
    WHEN 1,2 THEN 'x'
    ELSE 'y'
  END;
```

I'm expecting it to return 'x';

The more traditional code runs fine, however:

```
SELECT
  CASE 1
    WHEN 1 THEN 'x'
    WHEN 2 THEN 'x'
    ELSE 'y'
  END;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using the `CASE` syntax as provided by the procedural language `plpgsql`. This is *similar* but not identical to the *SQL* `CASE` syntax. Here is the link to the SQL version of [`CASE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-conditional.html).

Here you see, that `1,2` is not allowed, only a plain `expression`. So you could write:

```
SELECT
  CASE 
    WHEN 1 in (1,2) THEN 'x'
    ELSE 'y'
  END;
```

Comment: I tested plpgsql before posting, by moving my select statement into a function. ;)  I see how this works now.  Thanks!